# append an id onto the name of a table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a select statement

```
select * from schema.table_id
```

where ID is a number that is passed into a function
how do I append this ID onto the table I have tried || but that gave a syntax error. I have also tried using `concat('schema.table_, id::text)` but when that ran a `select * from %I, table name` that gave an error of relation "`schema.tablename`" does not exist I assume this is due to it being in quotes

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? A bit difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @kometen so the function is func(int) in the function i have an if statement that if statement calls from the table schema.table_id where the id is the int of the function. i need to append the id onto schema.table_ so that i can run the query

Comment: whether all tables are having same columns? Better to post the function definition what you have tried till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is limited to you problem mentioned in the question. You should write it in this way:

```
format('select * from %I.%I',schema_name,'table_'||id::text)
```

or

```
format('select * from "schema_name".%I','table_'||id::text)
```